# Showcase hub sites. Not showing

Tags: sharepoint-online, hub-site

[image]

Showcase hub site only working on some Comm sites, what am I missing?

Please let me know.

Comment: what is your issue? I can find this web part and use it on a modern page of a SharePoint Online Site regardless it is a Team site or Communication Site.

Comment: For some reason reason I can't find it on some Team site.